# Is there an entropy evaluation method with an unified length?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

For entropy, the most common one is Shannon entropy, however, it ignores time series of data. For instance, data 0x00001111 and 0x01010101 are given the same entropy. It is obvious that the second data is more disordered than the first one which mean the entropy of the second one should be larger.

So, I find the second approach: BiEntropy(https://github.com/sandialabs/bientropy). It is able to distinguish even the shortest binary string: 0x01 and 0x00 as the figure shows.

[image]

However, short binary with high bientropy value cannot be called as encryption-related (we usually think encryption related data have high entropy value and I also find the encryption part in a program according to high entropy data).

So, does anyone know any entropy method that offsets length effect? like entropy = shannon entropy*length (This is only the rough idea I think about, not rigorous)

Comment: I don't know what it means to "offset length effect".  I suggest you [edit] your question to state your requirements more precisely.  Note that in information theory entropy usually is considered a property of the random source used to generate output, not of a specific bitstring (though there are exceptions, such as Kolmogorov complexity).

Comment: I think I have made it clear but I will give more explanations to "offset length effect". Like I mentioned in the Bi-entropy, it is not that feasible that a short one "0x01" will have a very high entropy value. This is what I mean offset length effect. In other words, an entropy method considers both time series (BiEntropy) and event appearance (shannon entropy).